# Instant search function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, delay, onkeyup

I am using the following javascript for my instant search function (to detect when the visitor stops writing, so the function won't run on every single keyup).

It works but it’s more delay than 1000 milliseconds. Even if I set it to 200 milliseconds it’s 1-2 seconds delay before the instant search function runs.

Is there a better/faster way to detect when the visitor has stopped typing in the input (I only need it for Internet Explorer if that’s make any difference).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var delay = (function(){
var timer = 0;
return function(callback, ms){
clearTimeout (timer);
timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();

$('input').keyup(function() {
delay(function(){
//instant search function here
}, 1000 );
});

});
```

New idea: When I think about it the problem is that I can’t continue writing in the input filed when the function runs. Any solution for that and I will not be needing any delay function.

Answer (score 13):

```
function instantSearch(){ ... }

var timer;
$('input').keyup(function(){
   timer && clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(instantSearch, 200);
});
```

Comment: That’s so beautiful. I don't even care about the performance of it ;) Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it works a little bit better, can’t really tell. Tough you misspelled keyUp in the example above. Do you know if there is a way to let the visitor continue writing in the input even if the instantSearch function runs?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow you... Why couldn't they keep typing?  Your instantSearch function is going to fire every time they stop typing for at least .2 sec, so it may fire multiple times.  The only reason your search should block it is if you're firing a sync AJAX call, in which case making it ASYNC should solve your issues.

One more thing, you should bind the actual search value to the AJAX callback so that you know you're showing results for the correct thing.  e.g. if they type "test"<wait>"ing", you may fire off two AJAX calls, but don't want to show the results for the first one.

Comment: Works great. A function is misspelled, should be `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your instant search function making an AJAX request to return results? That might be the difference between setting the delay to 200ms and getting your response back 1-2s later.

Comment: Thanks for answering. No I am not making an ajax request. But I see what you mean (of course you are right). Still if I replace the search function with a simple alert function there is a similar behavior. When I think about it the problem is that I can’t continue writing in the input filed when the function runs. Any solution for that and I will not be needing any delay function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the keyup event it shouldn't be necessary to specify a delay unless there are specific limits on queries-per-second or something similar.

There's a fairly concise walkthrough here: http://blog.comperiosearch.com/2012/06/make-an-instant-search-application-using-json-ajax-and-jquery/