# Yii2 ActiveForm textInput onChange

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, pjax

I've gone through the following man
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/
and everything is just fine.
However I'd like to perform Pjax search through my form data WITHOUT click at Submit button.
Thus I'm trying to use onChange event however I can't find the way to do this.
I've found a lot of explanations for dropDownList, but there is no any info about textInput onChange event.

Comment: The problem is, that onchange only triggers when it loses the focus of its input element (see [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)). Try using a similar function like `keyup` or `oninput`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to create an instant search input with an delay:

[Instant search function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383976/instant-search-function-in-javascript)

Just modifiy your JavaScript-Search-Snippet like this:

```
$this->registerJs(
   'function instantSearch() {
        $.pjax.reload({container:"#countries"});  //Reload GridView
    }

    var timer;
    $("document").ready(function(){ 
        //$("#new_country").on("pjax:end", function() {
        $("input").keyUp(function(){
            timer && clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(instantSearch, 200);
        });
    });'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

field($model, 'interview_date')->textInput()->widget(DatePicker::classname(),[ 'pluginOptions' => [ 'autoclose'=>true, 'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy', 'todayHighlight' => true, 'startDate'=>'today' ], 'options' => [ 'placeholder' => 'Select Date ', 'onchange' => 'emptyfields(this.value);' ] ]) ?>