# ajax-like search with internal list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, search

I apologize ahead of time if the title was worded oddly!

I want to do an ajax-like search on a list I have on the client side (i.e. a list of friends). The list would look like this:

```
var friendList = new Array [
{
    name: "Mark",
    email: "mark@gmail.com",
    birthDate: "01/01/1980"
},
{
    name: "Steve",
    email: "steve@gmail.com",
    birthdate: "02/02/1980"
},
{
    name: "Frank",
    email: "frank@gmail.com",
    birthDate: "03/03/1980"
}
]
```

How would I search letter by letter with an input field like so:

```
<input type="search" id="searchFriends" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try something? on key events for example could help.

Comment: also search for "instant search" and you will find many examples, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383976/instant-search-function-in-javascript

Comment: @AmrElgarhy sorry I'm new so I wasn't sure where to start, but I'll take a look at it now!

Comment: no worried, we were all new, just make sure to put in your future questions what you have tried so far, and make sure that your questions are not answered previously, and don't say sorry again :) we are all here to learn from each others questions and answers.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Awesome thanks for the help!